# Find descendant elements that do not have a specific ancestor

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to be able to select an element and find all descendant elements with a specific class but are not contained with a similar parent element.  It's hard to describe:

Html:

```
<div class="js-test js-1">
    <div class="b">1</div>
    <div class="b">1</div>
    <div class="d">
        <div class="b">1</div>        
    </div>
    <div class="js-test js-2">
        <div class="b">2</div>
        <div class="b">2</div>
        <div class="b">2</div>
        <div class="d">
            <div class="b">2</div>        
        </div>
        <div class="js-test js-3">
            <div class="b">3</div>
            <div class="b">3</div>
            <div class="b">3</div>
            <div class="b">3</div>
            <div class="d">
                <div class="b">3</div>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Attempted jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function test(element)
    {
        var test2 = element.find('.b :not(.js-test .b)');
        console.log(test2.length);
    }
    
    console.clear();
    test($('.js-1'));
    test($('.js-2'));
    test($('.js-3'));
});
```

Expected Results:

> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

Actual Results:

> 0
>
> 0
>
> 0

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ku2pdn2j/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do some filtering to only count occurrences of `.b` where the closest `.js-test` equals `element`:

```
element.find('.b').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('.js-test').is(element);
}).length;
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ku2pdn2j/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The selector `.b :not(.js-test .b)` finds descendants of `.b` elements that are not `.js-test .b` elements. The problem with this selector is twofold:

- Every `.b` element is a descendant of a `.js-test` element. This includes the `.b` elements immediately nested within each context `.js-test` element *that you are testing*.
- The space between the first `.b` and the `:not()` represents a descendant selector, which also means that the element being represented by `:not()` could very well be a `:not(.b)` entirely and still match.

  But none of your `.b` elements have any element descendants, and this is the real reason why all of your test results are zero.

Since you can't directly create a selector corresponding to the context element (the argument `element`), you will need to write a custom filter function like the one proposed by billyonecan, and filter according to whether its closest `.js-test` ancestor is the context element.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
// descendant `.b` of `element`,
// descendant `.b` of `element`, not `.b`, not `.js-test`
var test2 = element.find("> .b, > :not(.b):not(.js-test) .b");
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ku2pdn2j/4/

---

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function test(element) {
            var test2 = element.find("> .b, > :not(.b):not(.js-test) .b");
            console.log(test2.length, test2);
        }
        
        console.clear();
        test($('.js-1'));
        test($('.js-2'));
        test($('.js-3'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
   <div class="js-test js-1">
        <div class="b">1</div>
        <div class="b">1</div>
        <div class="d">
            <div class="b">1</div>        
        </div>
        <div class="js-test js-2">
            <div class="b">2</div>
            <div class="b">2</div>
            <div class="b">2</div>
            <div class="d">
                <div class="b">2</div>        
            </div>
            <div class="js-test js-3">
                <div class="b">3</div>
                <div class="b">3</div>
                <div class="b">3</div>
                <div class="b">3</div>
                <div class="d">
                    <div class="b">3</div>        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something similiar to [billyonecan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28634703/209259)'s answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function test(element)
    {
        var all = element.find('.b');
        var exclude = element.find('.js-test .b');
        var test = all.not(exclude);
        console.log(test.length);
    }
    
    console.clear();
    test($('.js-1'));
    test($('.js-2'));
    test($('.js-3'));
});
```

Actual Results:

> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

The intended application's result set is so small that I don't believe there is any significant different in performance between any solution here.